# When do we use all the different collections in .NET?

Tags: .net, collections

In .NET we have a lot of different collection types. I'm usually good in picking the right one for my needs, but I noticed I don't always consider all the aspects of one (e.g. Like usability, maintainability, performance)

So when do we use:

- An Array
- A List
- A Dictionary
- A HashTable
- A HashSet
- A LinkedList
- Etc.

And why?

I was hoping for some good comparisons with good explanation (and maybe some code, to support it). I think there is a win for me (and hopefully more of us) here.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but this is too broad and opinion based. A _comparison_ is [not on topic on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in general.

Comment: [Choosing the right collection](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)

Comment: I don't agree that this is opinion based, a collection can be chosen by facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the collections excel in some areas and perform poorly in others.  As such the collection you use is largely based on its intended usage within the program.

Here is a break down of what each collection is usually used for.

**Array**
    *var array[] = new T[n] { /* n elements */ };*

- Indexed random access collection.
- Constant size collection (N elements for the life-time of the array).
- Ordered collection.

**List**
    *var list = new List<T>( );*
    *list.Add(default(T));*

- Indexed random access collection.
- Modifiable collection (addition and removal of items).
- Ordered collection.

**Dictionary**
    *var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>( );*

- Keyed random access collection.
- Modifiable collection (addition and removal of items).
- Usually constant time insertion, removal and look-up.
- Unordered collection.

**HashTable**
Prefer `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`; `HashTable` is a non-generic `Dictionary`

**HashSet**
    *var set = new HashSet<T>( );*
    *set.Add(default(T));*

- Constant time look-up.
- No requirement or facility to *get* an element, only to determine containment.

**LinkedList**
    *var linkedList = new LinkedList<T>( );*
    *linkedList.AddAfter(linkedList.First, default(T));*

- Constant time insertion and removal.
- Modifiable collection (addition and removal of items)
- Ordered collection.

The above is what I know, please don't accept it as fact and do your own research given the above.  If there is anything I've missed that should be included please let me know in the comments.

Comment: For what reasons would you choose an array over a list?

Comment: When you don't intend on adding or removing elements to the collection. Internally, a `List<T>` keeps track of an array `T[capacity]`. When the capacity has been reached, `List<T>` creates a new array with a new computed capacity (based on some rules) and copies over the references to existing elements from the old array.  To be honest, `List<T>` is my go to collection however I also make heavy use of exposing my collections as `IEnumerable<T>` when the only intended use of the collection across some boundary is to be enumerated.